# Criteria prohibiting asking further question on stackexange sites

Tags: support

I was going to ask my another question on superuser.com but instead of the question form
I was informed by the message

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting
>   questions from this account.

I don't know why this happened. I wasn't informed before that I'm doing something wrong
or break some rules of this forum.
What can I do to find out my mistakes and correct them?
Will I be able to ask new questions or my interaction with superuser.com definitely ended?

Comment: Duplicate of [the very same question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86591/criteria-prohibiting-asking-further-question-on-stack-exchange-sites) by the same user on MSO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some more details can be found in the Stack Exhange FAQ: [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Answer (score 7):

Your profile shows that ask a lot of questions which are closed as off topic.
(Currently that's 5/9, just over half of your total asked.)

This shows an unwillingness to appreciate the time given by others.

Every question that is closed as off topic or not a real question dings you and puts your account under automated watch. Continue that behaviour and you may find yourself in the position you are in today.

This is now a time for reflection and reading through the FAQ as to what topics and questions are allowed on Super User.

Deleted questions will also score against you in terms of overall quality and judgement. Pray for your questions to gather legitimate upvotes to pull you out of the sarlacc pit and you may be able to ask questions again.

Comment: OK, I will correct my bad questions but who will give me back the ability to ask questions? One of my questions was closed by you. It talks about readability, widely used concept related to software and typography.

Comment: The question about readability is more suited to User Interface or typography. @xra

Comment: OK, you're right but I don't know all the subsites yet and there was a tag readability, so the tag should be deleted in that case or other users will continue asking here.

Comment: Deleted questions are also taken into account in the screening filter. In fact, [in some cases](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029), it seems that deleting is considered as proof that the question was low quality or should not have been posted for other reasons.

Comment: yes, deletion is not really a good idea here. Only upvotes and *not sucking* can help you. That said, you can always answer and edit of course..